# SED/AWK/BASH expand alphanumeric delimited fields with '0' padding

Tags: bash, awk, sed, isc-dhcpd

I need help with a regular expression to expand any 1 character field to 2 characters with 0 padding. 0-9, a-f alphanumeric field.

Given:

```
echo $dhcp6_s46_cont_mapt 
0:5b:0:9:40:0:64:ff:9b:0:1:0:3:0:59:0:17:0:a:20:47:55:54:4c:36:26:0:6c:e1:80:e0:0:0:5d:0:4:1:0:0:0:
```

Expand to:

```
00:5b:00:09:40:00:64:ff:9b:00:01:00:03:00:59:00:17:00:0a:20:47:55:54:4c:36:26:00:6c:e1:80:e0:00:00:5d:00:04:01:00:00:00:
```

then remove colons (`:`) with:

```
updatedstring = ${dhcp6_s46_cont_mapt//:}

echo $updatedstring
005b0009400064ff9b000100 ... etc
```

Believe the answer should be along these lines:
's/ ([a-f0-9][a-f0-9][:])'|'s/([a-f0-9][:]) / 0\1 /' < $dhcp6_s46_cont_mapt
--for the expansion search.

Answer (score 3):

Why not keep everything in the (bash) shell?

```
$ dhcp6_s46_cont_mapt='0:5b:0:9:40:0:64:ff:9b:0:1:0:3:0:59:0:17:0:a:20:47:55:54:4c:36:26:0:6c:e1:80:e0:0:0:5d:0:4:1:0:0:0:'

$ IFS=: read -a arr <<<"$dhcp6_s46_cont_mapt"    
$ printf -v updatedstring '%02x' "${arr[@]/#/0x}"

$ echo "$updatedstring"
005b0009400064ff9b0001000300590017000a204755544c3626006ce180e000005d000401000000
```

Comment: This works great in ubuntu, but I have an embedded linux busy box supported system. And I get a syntax error:                                                                                                            # export new_dhcp6_s46_mapt=0:5b:0:9:40:0:64:ff:9b:0:1:0:3:0:59:0:17:0:a:20:47:55:54:4c:36:26:0:6c:e1:80:e0:0:0:5d:0:4:1:0:0:0
# printf -v updatedstring '%02x' "${arr[@]/#/0x}"
-sh: syntax error: bad substitution

Comment: @R.Gulde that's expected - busybox `sh` is not SED/AWK/BASH...

Answer (score 2):

With POSIX `sh` syntax:

```
updatedstring=$(IFS=:; printf %02x $(printf 0x%s: $dhcp6_s46_cont_mapt))
```

A maybe unusual application of `dd`:

```
updatestring=$(
  printf %s "$dhcp6_s46_cont_mapt" |
    tr : '\n' |
    dd cbs=2 conv=block 2> /dev/null |
    tr ' ' 0
)
```

Answer (score 0):

using `sed` and character-class `[[:xdigit:]]` for hex digits only, you could do:

```
sed -E ':a s/(^|:)([[:xdigit:]])(:|$)/\10\2\3/; ta; s/://g'
```

- `[[:xdigit:]]` matches on (0-9a-f; case insensitive)

Comment: #! /bin/sh

new_dhcp6_s46_cont_mapt=0:5b:0:9:40:0:64:ff:9b:0:1:0:3:0:59:0:17:0:a:20:47:55:54:4c:36:26:0:6c:e1:80:e0:0:0:5d:0:4:1:0:0:0
echo $new_dhcp6_s46_cont_mapt
echo 'Run sed to expand'
echo 'From:'
echo $new_dhcp6_s46_cont_mapt
echo 'To'
x="$(echo $new_dhcp6_s46_cont_mapt | sed -E ':a s/(^|:)([[:xdigit:]])(:|$)/\10\2\3/; ta; s/://g')"
echo "$x

Answer (score 0):

Should work in busybox:

```
djunk=0:5b:0:9:40:0:64:ff:9b:0:1:0:3:0:59:0:17:0:a:20:47:55:54:4c:36:26:0:6c:e1:80:e0:0:0:5d:0:4:1:0:0:0:
djunk=$(djunk=:${djunk%:}; printf %02x ${djunk//:/ 0x})
echo "$djunk"

005b0009400064ff9b0001000300590017000a204755544c3626006ce180e000005d000401000000
```

Assuming default `IFS`, can be easily fixed (refinement left as an exercise to the reader)

Answer (score 0):

Using any awk in any shell on every UNIX box:

```
$ var='0:5b:0:9:40:a:b:64'
$ echo "$var" | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"} {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i=substr("0"$i,length($i))} 1'
00:5b:00:09:40:0a:0b:64
```

Otherwise, Using a sed that has `-E` to enable EREs:

```
$ var='0:5b:0:9:40:a:b:64'
$ echo "$var" | sed -E 's/(^|:)([^:])(:|$)/\10\2\3/g; s/(^|:)([^:])(:|$)/\10\2\3/g; s/://g'
005b0009400a0b64
```

here's what's happening in steps in the sed script:

```
$ echo "$var" | sed -E 's/(^|:)([^:])(:|$)/\10\2\3/g'
00:5b:00:9:40:0a:b:64

$ echo "$var" | sed -E 's/(^|:)([^:])(:|$)/\10\2\3/g; s/(^|:)([^:])(:|$)/\10\2\3/g'
00:5b:00:09:40:0a:0b:64

$ echo "$var" | sed -E 's/(^|:)([^:])(:|$)/\10\2\3/g; s/(^|:)([^:])(:|$)/\10\2\3/g; s/://g'
005b0009400a0b64
```